# TTFB is slow from Azure CDN with Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I'm using Akamai CDN with Azure, with Blob Storage as backend. When I run the tests with google speed test.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

I get the following,

> Reduce server response time In our test, your server responded in **0.23**
>   seconds. There are many factors that can slow down your server
>   response time. Please read our recommendations to learn how you can
>   monitor and measure where your server is spending the most time.

How would I improve the TTFB with Azure?
I don't have any servers serving the contents.

Does moving to Verizon Premium increases TTFB? or what should I do?

Content served is all full javascripts, html and css scripts.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the option of **Optimized for** that you choose when you create a CDN endpoint?

Comment: What score do you get without CDN? It could be more something that can be enabled with your origin.

Comment: Optimized for Blob Storage. Score for the same app 53/100 on akamai and 66/100 on Verizon Premium. I can see the server response time is very fast with verizon premium and my objects are less than 1MB.

Comment: 1)Do you choose **General web delivery** in **[Optimized for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-optimization-overview)** drop-down list? 2)Do you refer to CSS and JavaScript file using blob url or CDN in your html page?

Answer (score 0):

To speed up your website by reducing TTFB, you may want to look into using the Speculation Rules API to do 'smart prefetching' of the page the user is likely to navigate to next. We've used it on the CDN Planet website and with success.

Speculation Rules is a new browser API, landing in Chrome/Edge browsers by end of 2023, but you can already use it on your website today by participating in the Chrome Origin Trial.

I wrote a (long) blog post about it here: https://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/how-improve-ttfb-on-cloudflare-with-speculation-rules/

We're on Cloudflare, but Speculation Rules will help speed up any website on any CDN, especially if the HTML is not served from CDN cache (cache miss).